# How to open Play Store to specific app on Android TV?

Tags: google-play, android-tv

I would like to open a link to a specific app in the Play Store on Android TV.

The normal way of doing it does not work

```
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.vending",
                "com.google.android.finsky.activities.LaunchUrlHandlerActivity");
        intent.setComponent(comp);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
        startActivity(intent);
```

This opens Google Play, but does not go to the app. Instead, a dialog pops up saying "To view this content, install and setup a web browsing app"

How can I get it to open the page for a specific app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I feel stupid, I just had to .trim() my packageName because it had a newline at the end.

If anyone else is looking for this, the above code works to open apps in the Play Store on Android TV.